# Bind Results in C# using SQL prepared statements

Tags: c#, sql, prepared-statement

Using this:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SERVER;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;User Instance=False");
myConnection.Open();

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT BusinessName FROM Businessess WHERE BusinessID = @Param2", myConnection);

SqlParameter myParam2 = new SqlParameter("@Param2", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
myParam2.Value = 1;
myCommand.Parameters.Add(myParam2);

MessageBox.Show(myCommand); //How do I bind results to show as string?
```

How do I bind the results of a prepared statement to a variable so that I may manipulate them?

Comment: Why don't you use Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SERVER;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;User Instance=False"))
using (SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT BusinessName FROM Businessess WHERE BusinessID = @Param2";
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", myParam2);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            string businessName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("BusinessName"));
            MessageBox.Show(businessName);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Sorry, no business found with id = {0}", myParam2));
        }
    }
}
```

Things to notice:

- disposable resources are wrapped in using statements to ensure proper disposal even in case of exceptions
- simplification of the parameter passed to the sql command
- call the `ExecuteReader` on the command in order to retrieve an object allowing you to read the returned resultset.

Comment: not a fan of .AddWithValue(), but otherwise nice work suggesting using blocks, .CreateCommand(), and of course actually calling an Execute__() function.

Comment: How do I use DbDataReader reader? Is there a namespace I need to include to use that?

Comment: @DanKanze, of course, it's the `System.Data.Common` namespace.

Comment: I included it, but I keep getting "No mapping exists from object type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter to a known managed provider native type." hung up on using (DbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())

Comment: @DanKanze, try using a `SqlDataReader` instead of a `DbDataReader`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov You are a golden god.